# mouse.get_pressed() inconsistent/returning (0, 0, 0)

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent, return-value

edit (solved): using event.button seems to have done the trick. When it returns 0, 0, 0 it returns the correct mouse button (1 = left, 3 = right)

I've tried looking up solutions to this but in every answer it seems the person didn't know about or forgot to include for event in pg.event.get() .. the mouse detection in pygame has stopped working reliably and I'm not sure if it's a hardware error, my code is bad or something else. Here is a simplified version of my game loop for the mouse:

```
while running:
     for event in pg.event.get():
            pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if grid_space.get_rect(x=(adj_x), y=(adj_y)).collidepoint(pos):
                    if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
                        do_thing()
                    elif event.button == 4:
                        do_thing()
                    elif event.button == 5:
                        do_thing()
                    else:
                        print(pg.mouse.get_pressed())
                        do_thing()
```

I moved the primary mouse button in to the else because it's the only way to make the most important action more reliable at the moment, but by printing the else result I also found that one in every 4 or 5 clicks returns (0, 0, 0) rather than (1, 0, 0). I've tried different ways of writing the expression, simplifying the structure, increasing the Pygame clock and nothing is working.

Has anyone encountered this and is there a solution?

edit: I've run another test saving the get_pressed result to a variable immediately and it still returns 0, 0, 0 so I'm pretty sure its state hasn't changed from MOUESBUTTONDOWN to the time its called.

Comment: What is your OS and which pygame version do you use?

Comment: Windows, pygame 1.9.6

Comment: get mouse pos  outside of the event loop

Comment: The pressed key is stored in the `button`  attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object.  `if event.button == 0:`

Comment: @hippozhipos where should it be then? Just in the game loop?

Comment: When do you save the state to a variable? I you save the states to a variable in the loop that doesn't change anything because the event occurred a long time before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) get the current state of the mouse buttons. The state of the buttons may have been changed, since the mouse event occurred. Note that the events are stored in a queue and you will receive the stored events later in the application by [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). Meanwhile the state of the button may have been changed because of this he button which causes the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event is stored in the `button` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object immediately. In the event loop, whn you get the event the state of `event.button` and `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` may be different.
The same goes for [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos). The position of the mouse is stored in the attribute `pos`
Use `event.button` and `event.pos` rather than `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` and `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`:

```py
while running:
     for event in pg.event.get():
            
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               print(event.button)

               if grid_space.get_rect(topleft=(adj_x, adj_y)).collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if event.button == 2:
                        do_thing()
                    elif event.button == 4:
                        do_thing()
                    elif event.button == 5:
                        do_thing()
                    else:
                        do_thing()
```

`pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` are not intended to be used in the event loop. The functions should be used directly in the application loop.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work at least on my system. The event buttons seem to work for scrolling with 4 and 5 but I get no response at all when I change pg.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:to event.button == 2

Comment: @Enemigo You won't get an event if no button was pressed. Put `print(event.button)` directly after  `if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` to see which button was pressed.

Comment: Ok I think I follow you now. I'm getting a 1 and an 0, 0, 0 when I print the button and get_pressed state. Let me revise this and get back to you

Comment: Yep, I think this did the trick. Thanks for the help, is the command just being overwritten then? I've only been programming a few months.

Comment: @Enemigo I've extended the explanation in the answer.